# Is the tensor product of a monoidal category associative?

Tags: category-theory

A strict monoidal category is a monoid in $\operatorname{Cat}$, i.e. a category $\mathcal{M}$, together with a functor $\otimes\colon\mathcal{M}\times\mathcal{M}\to\mathcal{M}$ and a distiguished object $U$ such that $\otimes\circ (1\times \otimes)=\otimes\circ (\otimes\times 1)$ and for every object $C\otimes U=C=U\otimes C$.

A monoidal category is a category $\mathcal{M}$, together with a functor $\otimes\colon\mathcal{M}\times\mathcal{M}\to\mathcal{M}$, a distiguished object $U$ and three natural isomorphisms making a pentagon and a triangle commute.

My question is: is the functor $\otimes$ of a monoidal category associative, as it is in a strict monoidal category?

Comment: I think no. In this case associativity is only an "associative constraint", not an identity.

Comment: It is a monoid ..... in (Cat, *, 1) . You need to spell out the monoidal structure, and here you pick the cartesian one. There is another symetric closed monoidal structure (cf  Power premonoidal categories and notions of computations http://www.eecs.qmul.ac.uk/~edmundr/pubs/mscs97/premoncat.ps)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the three isomorphisms you refer to is the associator, which makes $\otimes$ associative "up-to-isomorphism." The most important difference between a monoidal and a strict monoidal category is that the associativity is relaxed in this way.

Comment: Just as addendum on the lingo of categorists, it's quite possible they would describe the (non-strict) monoidal category as being "associative" with the "up-to-isomorphism" being implied which is a bit of an abuse of language. This can even be justified via e.g. Homotopy Type Theory where an internal construction of a seemingly strict monoidal category may well externally correspond to a weak monoidal category.

Answer (score 1):

Spelling out each components that makes a strict monoidal category a monoid in (Cat, $\times$, 1) :

To define a monoid in this monoidal category, you need  $\mathcal{M}\in Cat$, $\otimes\colon\mathcal{M}\times\mathcal{M}\to\mathcal{M}$, $U: 1\to\mathcal{M}$ and commutation with 3 diagrams inherited from the monoidal structure of (Cat, $\times$, 1).

If you do not identify $U: 1\to\mathcal{M}$ with $U\in \mathcal{M}$, you conditions read out as $\otimes.(U\times id_M) : 1\times M \to M\times M \to M = \lambda_{Cat} : 1\times M  \to M $ (and likewise for the association axiom which you did not write)

Whereas the corresponding diagram (in Cat) defining a monoidal category has some (iso) transformation between those 2 functors.

So what you would need is to look as pseudo-monoids, to have exactly the definition of a monoidal category.

If you see $U: 1\to\mathcal{M}$ as $U\in \mathcal{M}$, this means that $\otimes$ is not associative, but that every time you have a way of going from one way of parenthesizing to another, there is a corresponding transformation between the two resulting composed objects.

This idea is captured in the notion of a bicategory, and a indeed (the delooping of) a monoidal category (or a pseudo-monoid in (Cat,$\times$,1)) is just a bicategory with a single object.

You might also stop thinking about 0, 1, 2, 3, etc.. objects to consider how those structures allow you to pick *any* numbers $n$ of objects, and relate the way they compose : they are all equal or at least *related* depending if you are in strict, or in normal monoidal categories.